# How to install M2E in Eclipse Mars 2.0

Tags: eclipse, maven

I had Maven installed by default at my ECLIPSE MARS 2.0 . I wanted to take the latest version of M2E and i go to Help-->Install New Software--> and followed all the steps and it was installed . Now when I want to create a new project I do not anymore have the option to create a Maven project. I am really confused what is happening to my eclipse. Can anyone provide me an answer and a solution?

Remark: In my terminal when i type **mvn --version**  the result is *command not found*

Comment: m2E is plugin maven for eclipse and it's true when you'll type in your terminal mvn --version it will not wrk because u didn'"t install maven in your computer. Maven and m2e are not the same thing. You have to install Maven in your computer and configure it in your input variables and then you can configure m2e in your eclipse to access to the folder of your installed maven

Comment: @Hohenheim  The thing that annoys me is " I do not know why when I try to create new project in eclipse i do not have the option Maven"

Comment: Are you sure that your update didn't mess up your installation? Is m2e still installed (you can verift it in "Help > About... > Installation details > Installed software". If it's missing here, you can try to reinstall m2e only.

Comment: @alex10 : Normally if you are using Eclipse Mars you got M2e embdded : installed in Eclipse Mars so normally you can add new project Maven : that's a little bit weird . You can delete it and re install Eclipse Mars without adding any plugin and try to create your project Maven